# what means the "f" in Location(32.9f, -117.2f);

Tags: java

what means the "f" in the lecture of 32.9(latitude) and -117.2(longitude) in the following code:

```
Location(32.9f, -117.2f);
```

Comment: It means a `float` literal. Without the `f` it would be a double literal.

Answer (score 2):

It means the numbers are of type `float`.